# how to take value of tapped column/bar of winrt xaml column series chart using c#

Tags: winrt-xaml

how to take value of tapped column/bar of winrt xaml column series chart.
i want to open other chart using the value of each bar..

my code is:

```
 <Charting:Chart x:Name="chart" Title="My Performance"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="895"  Height="548" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" >



<Charting:ColumnSeries x:Name="mychart"   Padding="10" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#FF233083"  Background="Yellow"   IndependentValuePath="TestCode"  DependentValuePath="Percentage" IsSelectionEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,4" Tapped="mychart_Tapped" >
```

i didn't get values from selecteditem thanks........

Comment: What do you mean you didn't get values from selecteditem? Are you getting anything in the `Tapped` event in your ColumnSeries? What I would probably suggest is editing the ColumnSeries template and adding a button wrapper, setting the `Command` of the wrapper to an `ICommand` in your VM and passing the `DataContext` as a `Binding` in the `CommandParameter`.

Comment: actually i am using column series on run time means adding chart from server side coding like 'ColumnSeries columnchart=new ColumnSeries and made a tappevent of it. i am able to open other things on tap but don't know how to get value of each bar of column series...

Comment: Are they available in `chart.Series`?

Comment: yas i am using like 'columnseries columnchart=new colmnseries' and after that add this series to chart which is taken in xaml page as shown in above coding '<Charting:Chart x:Name="chart" Title="My Performance"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="895"  Height="548" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" >

'

Comment: So, you said that you can't get the value of each bar. Do as I said in my first comment. Create a Button in the ColumnSeries item style. Bind that button's Command to an ICommand in your VM. Put the DataContext of the bar into the CommandParameter using an empty Binding. You will now be able to access the data on clicking the column.

Comment: can you show me some example.i don't know how to add button from server side coding...using c#

Comment: What do you mean add a button from server side?